# With Samsung's Knox proven weakness, how should I secure my Samsung device?

Tags: mobile, vulnerability

[This post](http://threatpost.com/nsa-approved-samsung-knox-stores-pin-in-cleartext/109018) shows that the device pin is stored in the clear, which presents a major weakness in device security.

Can I just delete the file? Or is there a better way to protect my device?

It appears the original post refers to Consumer Knox (as @Flash posted) but the problem still remains: How do I protect myself appropriately when my PIN is stored in the clear?

Comment: Having worked with the Knox team, I know they are fixing this problem. I'm not sure there is a way to bolster the Knox container at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ares](http://mobilesecurityares.blogspot.co.uk/), who posted the original vulnerability, has added [a couple of updates](http://mobilesecurityares.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/why-samsung-knox-isnt-really-fort-knox.html?m=1)

> Samsung mentioned the following in their press release: "Concerning the second issue, KNOX does save the encryption key required to auto-mount the container’s file system in TrustZone. However, unlike what is implied in the blog, the access to this key is strongly controlled. Only trusted system processes can retrieve it, and KNOX Trusted Boot will lock down the container key store in the event of a system compromise."
>
> I think Samsung speaks here about their Knox Agent. At the beginning of my analysis I used geohots towelroot to gain root access on the Samsung device. During the analysis the phone wanted to update some "Samsung Security Policies". After the update the Agent blocked the root access to the phone. So this agent seems to be working like a usual Anti-Virus tool. It can only detect attacks if it knows the attack. And as we all know, Anti-Viruses are useless against unknown attacks :). This is the same for their so called "TrustZone".

Which does suggest Samsung are taking the view that an attacker with root access can do any damage they want anyway - but failing to include an understanding that various attacks will get you to root. Not sure how I feel about this one.

A further update on that same page now says:

> Apparently Samsung said in their press release that user should try out My Knox, as Knox Personal is deprecated. I just tried to install it but sadly My Knox only works on Samsung Galaxy S5 and Samsung Galaxy Note4. So Samsung, you're leaving all devices older than the S5 with a vulnerable version of Samsung Knox??

So there **is a fix** but only on newer hardware that hs TrustZone functionality.

Answer (score 0):

this post refers to a previous version of Samsung Knox: Consumer Knox. This is not the version which has enterprise and government grade security - which includes the use of MDM. It has only been available on Samsung Galaxy S4 and Note 3. No other models. Therefore no fix on other models. However, there is a new version of Knox for Consumers which is built on the same fundamentals like the current enterprise solution - but without MDM and other enterprise features. As this is a new product, it is of course only available on current models.

The enterprise security solution Samsung Knox in the new version of Knox 2.x is available also on older models like e.g. Galaxy S4. However, as it relies on TrustZone, certain hardware features are required which is the reason why Knox cannot be made available on older models.

Comment: That is interesting Flash. Thanks. I'll update the question to make it clearer, as this is still an issue.